# binary '++': '_Ty' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

Tags: c++

I have a vector:
vector insects;

I overloaded the operation ++ for a parent class and subclass:

```
Organism& Organism::operator++ () {
    breed_tick = breed_tick + 1;
    return *this;
}
```

and

```
Organism& Doodlebug::operator++ () {
    breed_tick = breed_tick + 1;
    starve_tick = starve_tick + 1;
    if (starve_tick == time_till_starve) {
        alive = false;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Then I access the element of insects and do ++

insects.at(i)++;

binary '++': '_Ty' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

I am at a lost of what I am doing wrong.

Comment: what type is the vector insects? operator at return a reference to that type. Does it implement operator++? furthermore, are you sure that Doodlebug::operator++ should return a reference to Organism instead a reference to Doodlebug?

Comment: `operator++()` is the prefix operator. The postfix operator is `operator++(int)`.

Comment: Note that the postfix increment (and decrement) is normally expected to return the value that the object had before incrementing, like it does for primitive types and everything in the standard library. (And thus can't return `*this` or a reference.)

Comment: It was, thank you -_-